# Entitiy Framework code-first migrations in multiple development environments

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working on a project that uses **EF6** with **code-first migrations**.
All the work till now was done on a Dev. environment, including the DB migrations.

I need to deploy the code to another environment (QA), however I've stumbled into a problem:
The DB exists, however there are no tables (I've created the DB manually).

Currently, the code in QA throws `Invalid object name 'dbo.__MigrationHistory'.` and truly this table doesn't exist in QA, it only exists in DEV where migrations were first enabled.

What is the best practice to work with migrations in multiple development environments (`DEV => QA => STG => PROD`)?
What is my best course of action?

**UPDATE**:
I've created the `dbo.__MigrationHistory` and the schema manually and populated the migrations table from the DEV table. The question still stands since I'll have to deploy to STG and PROD later this month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you utilize some kind of continuous integration, you could proceed as follows:

1. create build configurations in your migrations project that will transform
   connection strings to fit environments' requirements (with XDT) on build,
2. build the project using MSBuild using respective configuration parameter,
3. use migrate.exe (e.g. from EF Nuget package's folder) to run migrations using the built DLL.

If you don't do CI, then you can just follow the first step and always deploy with your migrations project built with respective build configuration. 
**Notice**: to mess up with __MigrationHistory table manually is never good practice.

To create database you can use `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` initializer.

Comment: migrations project as in DAL project or you make a separate project for migrations some how?

Comment: Actually doesn't matter for the steps I wrote. We have a separate dll that holds all entities, `EntityTypeConfigurations`, `DbMigrationConfigurations` and the `DbMigrations` and nothing else.

Comment: Aren't the DbMigrations supposed to be in the same project as the Entities? I too have all the entities in a separate project (nuget) however my DbMigrations and DbContext in my dal project in my main solution. However, I will explore you're proposal, since it makes sense to me. I still dont have a definitive answer though about deploying to totally clean environments that do not have __MigrationHistory

Comment: I do have them in one dll. As i wrote.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options you can try:

1- use database initializers:

```
Database.SetInitializer<UserDbContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<UserDbContext, Configuration>());
```

2- use ssdt to migrate tables and data between environments (qa, dev, prod, etc)

Comment: 1 wouldn't work because the new database doesn't have the `__MigrationHistory` table yet. 2 is what I did, however I hope there is a better way, it feels hacky to duplicate the schema and copy the migration table data